# How do I create/configure my own AMQP ContainerFactory in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

I added this as an attempt to create and configure my own `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` to replace the default

```
@Bean
open fun myFactory(cf: ConnectionFactory): SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory {
    val factory = SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory()
    factory.setConnectionFactory(cf)
    factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false)
    factory.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(MessagePostProcessor {
        it.messageProperties.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
        return@MessagePostProcessor it
    })
    return factory
}
```

When the code is running I still see

```
o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Rejecting messages (requeue=true)
```

which leads me to believe that spring boot isn't using my ContainerFactory. I suppose I don't really care if it's using mine if I can configure it correctly. What's the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/#using-container-factories).

The framework looks for a factory named `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` by default, unless you set the `containerFactory` property on the annotation.

> By default, the infrastructure looks for a bean named rabbitListenerContainerFactory as the source for the factory to use to ...

To override Boot's bean, name it `rabbitListenerContainerFactory`.

When doing that, it's generally best to use the configurer so your boot properties will be applied...

```
@Bean(name = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

    factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false)
    factory.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(MessagePostProcessor {
        it.messageProperties.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
        return@MessagePostProcessor it
    })

    return factory;
}
```